# Error while installing PMD in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, pmd

When trying to install PMD in eclipse kepler , through Help -> Install New Software --> Add 
--> and I provide the link "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/" in the pop up. Up on cliking ok , Im getting following error.

Unable to read repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/content.xml.
peer not authenticated

I checked my network connection and it is "Native". Please help me in resolving the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I replied to this exact post when it was [asked/crossposted two days ago at CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/637829/vc/Installing-PMD-eclipse-kepler-error).

My answer was

> It's probably a proxy/firewall/network issue. The good news is that
>   [the PMD site](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/integrations.html#eclipse) provides an alternate way to install. You download the
>   zip file yourself and point to that from the Eclipse installer. (See
>   the link I provided for the exact steps)